How to extend Polars API to work on both DataFrame and LazyFrame
I would like to extend the Polars API as described in the docs, but I would like the same namespace to work on both DataFrames and LazyFrames.
Pretend I have a simple DataFrame, which could just as easily be a LazyFrame...
import polars as pl
a = pl.DataFrame({"col1": ["A", "B", "A", "A", "B"], "col2": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
b = b.lazy()

I want to use a namespace to do "stuff" to both of these. For simplicity, let's just do a simple group_by sum. I could write namespaces for each separately:
@pl.api.register_dataframe_namespace("stuff")
class StuffFrame:
    def __init__(self, df: pl.DataFrame):
        self._df = df

    def do_stuff(self) -> pl.DataFrame:
        df = self._df.group_by("col1").agg(pl.col("*").sum())
        return df


@pl.api.register_lazyframe_namespace("stuff")
class StuffLazyFrame:
    def __init__(self, ldf: pl.LazyFrame):
        self._ldf = ldf

    def do_stuff(self) -> pl.LazyFrame:
        ldf = self._ldf.group_by("col1").agg(pl.col("*").sum())
        return ldf

a1 = a.stuff.do_stuff()
b1 = b.stuff.do_stuff()

But then I have to maintain code in two functions. Instead, I could convert the DataFrame to a LazyFrame in the DataFrame namespace and then call the LazyFrame namespace:
@pl.api.register_dataframe_namespace("stuff")
class StuffFrame:
    def __init__(self, df: pl.DataFrame):
        self._df = df

    def do_stuff(self) -> pl.DataFrame:
        df = self._df.lazy().stuff.do_stuff().collect()  #<-- convert to Lazy, do stuff, then collect
        return df


@pl.api.register_lazyframe_namespace("stuff")
class StuffLazyFrame:
    def __init__(self, ldf: pl.LazyFrame):
        self._ldf = ldf

    def do_stuff(self) -> pl.LazyFrame:
        ldf = self._ldf.group_by("col1").agg(pl.col("*").sum()) #<-- only maintain code in one namespace
        return ldf


a2 = a.stuff.do_stuff()
b2 = b.stuff.do_stuff()

Is this an appropriate approach, or is there a better way to deal with this?

Perhaps you could accomplish some of this with scan_csv?

Perhaps using pipe() is a solution to help maintain code in one place and keep the namespaces uncluttered.
Place the heavy lifting code in a helper function, then use pipe to call the helper function in each namespace. Since pipe can be used on both DataFrame and LazyFrame, this can keep the namespace classes a bit cleaner.
def _do_stuff(df):
    # do the heavy work here and use pipe to call it
    return df.group_by("col1").agg(pl.col("*").sum())


@pl.api.register_dataframe_namespace("stuff")
class StuffFrame:
    def __init__(self, df: pl.DataFrame):
        self._df = df

    def do_stuff(self) -> pl.DataFrame:
        return self._df.pipe(_do_stuff)


@pl.api.register_lazyframe_namespace("stuff")
class StuffLazyFrame:
    def __init__(self, ldf: pl.LazyFrame):
        self._ldf = ldf

    def do_stuff(self) -> pl.LazyFrame:
        return self._ldf.pipe(_do_stuff)

a2 = a.stuff.do_stuff()
b2 = b.stuff.do_stuff()


pipe() may not be entirely necessary here. You can also just call _do_stuff like you would any other function.
def do_stuff(self) -> pl.DataFrame: return _do_stuff(self._df) and similarly for the LazyFrame class.
I do like the solution of putting the logic in a function.

If a separate namespace is not the most important thing to you, here is another alternative, also able to be utilised with pipe.
a = pl.DataFrame({"col1": ["A", "B", "A", "A", "B"], "col2": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
b = a.lazy()

def do_stuff(df: pl.DataFrame | pl.LazyFrame) -> pl.DataFrame | pl.LazyFrame:
    # LazyFrame.lazy() is a no-op, so this works for both input types
    output = df.lazy().group_by("col1").agg(pl.col("*").sum())
    if isinstance(df, pl.DataFrame):
      output = output.collect()
    return output

# You can then use this function in either of these ways
a2 = do_stuff(a)
a2 = a.pipe(do_stuff)
# And the same way for `b`
b2 = do_stuff(b)
b2 = b.pipe(do_stuff)


# Pipe is great to keep a chain going
(
    a
    .filter(pl.col("col2") < 5)
    .pipe(do_stuff)
    .with_columns(col3=pl.concat_str("col1", "col2"))
)

